# Get a page with Selenium but wait for element value to not be empty

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm grabbing a web page using Selenium, but I need to wait for a certain value to load. I don't know what the value will be, only what element it will be present in.

It seems that using the expected condition `text_to_be_present_in_element_value` or `text_to_be_present_in_element` is the most likely way forward, but I'm having difficulty finding any actual documentation on how to use these and I don't know if they come before or after the page Get:

```py
webdriver.get(url)
```

---

Linked answers to this both rely on knowing what the expected text value will be. In the first one, it explicitly shows the expected text hardcoded into the `WebDriverWait` call. Furthermore, neither of the linked answers even remotely touch upon the final part of my question:

> [whether] they come before or after the page Get

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as a duplicate question. The answers to both linked questions both rely on knowing what the text value is going to be, and I specifically said here that I don't know what the value will be.

Comment: Well, SO says "If these questions don’t resolve your question, ask a new one", so I guess I'll just post the exact same question again and hope someone reads it before closing it this time.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64976243/3900915